# Can I use socket.io with a php based free heroku app?

Tags: php, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I have a free php based Heroku app and I have a php login system. I would like users to be able to chat via socket.io after logging in. I can run either the node.js server or the php server, but not both. I have researched and it looks like that is not possible. I do not want to re code the login system for node.js, what can I do to allow them to chat while keeping the php login system?

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to have a websockets server running alongside a PHP app on Heroku. Only web dynos can receive HTTP traffic on Heroku, and only on the specified port.

https://help.heroku.com/8R7OO0ZV/can-i-run-a-websockets-server-using-php-on-heroku

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.